# Проверка и сравнения input radio

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars

Здраствуйте. Создаю опрос, использую для этого шаблонизатор handlebars. Данные в шаблон подгружатся c json. Не получаеться реализовать проверку input(взятие их value) и сравнение данного value, со значением которое записано в json.

```html
    {{#each quizContent}}
        <div class="quiz_item">
            <div class="quiz_question">
                {{this.question}}
            </div>

            <div class="quiz_answers">
                {{#each answer}}
                <label class="quiz_radiobtn" for="{{../form_name}}{{@index}}">
              <input type="radio" name = "{{../form_name}}" value = {{@index}} id ="{{../form_name}}{{@index}}">
              <span class="radio-indicator"></span>
              {{this}}
            </label><br/> {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
```